# Model comparison for robust linear mixed effects models

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-selection, model-comparison

I have fitted two robust linear mixed effects models, `null.model` and `full.model`, with same random-effects term, `(1 | id)`, to a data set using `robustlmm::rlmer`. These models only differ by a predictor `x`:

```
null.model <- rlmer(y ~ (1 | id), data)
full.model <- rlmer(y ~ x + (1 | id), data)
```

I have chosen to fit robust LMMs over LMMs (provided by `lme4::lmer` or `lmerTest::lmer`) since I saw that the residuals (of LMMs) were not following the straight line at the ends when I plotted Q-Q plots against a standard Gaussian distribution.

I am now facing a problem of comparing these two models. [The manual for robustlmm](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/robustlmm.pdf) says

> ... the log likelihood is not defined for the robust estimates returned by `rlmer`.

So, I can't perform a likelihood ratio test on the lines of `anova(null.model, full.model)`. Is there any way to compare these two models? Am I missing any important statistical assumptions that I should be aware of before I think of comparing these models?

Comment: Since the models differ only in whether `x` is included as a fixed effect or not, isn't one approach to do the model comparison to test whether the `x` coefficient estimate is 0 or not. Obviously, that's a Wald-type of test, not a likelihood ratio test.